# Camera API store in ImageView

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I want to use the Android's Camera API to display an image in ImageView. I saw the other available solutions which displays the live camera feed in a SurfaceView but I want to store it as an image and display it on an ImageView, which I will manually update on the click of a Button. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I saw the other available solutions which displays the live camera feed in a SurfaceView

That is called the preview, and it is useful for people to be able to tell what the camera is pointed at. Or, to quote [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#camera-preview):

> For users to effectively take pictures or video, they must be able to see what the device camera sees.

---

> I want to store it as an image and display it on an ImageView, which I will manually update on the click of a Button

This is called "taking a picture" or "[capturing pictures](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-picture)". Using the original camera API, to take a picture, you call `takePicture()` on your `Camera` object.

The Android developer documentation has [a training section](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html) on creating a custom camera app, in addition to the documentation that I linked to above.